# C++:Getting access violation in LPTSTR string manipulation

Tags: c++

I have a string say

```
 LPTSTR orgString =_T("abc\refg\rhij");
```

Here task is I need to remove a character '\r'(carriage return).
I don't want to use again new temporary buffer, using existing string with some manipulations I need to remove '\r' character.

But while moving the contents inside the "orgString" I am getting access violation exception.

Even simple statement `orgString[3] = orgString[4]`; giving access violation.

Don't know where I am thinking wrong please help me!!!

Comment: `orgString` points to (the first character of) a string constant. Modifying a string constant is undefined behavior. The declaration will not compile with a fully conforming C++11 or later compiler. For pure Windows programming use `wchar_t` based text handling. Then the right tool for you here is the `wstring` type, from the `<string>` header. Don't use the silly Windows 9x compatibility macros like `_T`. Compile with the `UNICODE` symbol defined.

Comment: No I don't want to use string.h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: but what I read is... LPTSTR will allow string modification unlike LPCSTR

Comment: The declaration should better look like `wstring orgString = L"abc\refg\rhij";`

Comment: I need to return LPTSTR type only so that other function will take it as input.